# Redux-Saga: UI blocking until api calls return for chunk of api request. How we can achieve this without blocking ui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-worker, redux-saga

```
function* getTagsAllImages(dataList = []) {
  const chunkedList = yield call(chunk, dataList, 5);

  for (let list of chunkedList) {
    const requests = list.map(item => call(getStoreLableimage, item._id, item.image));

    const responses = yield all(requests);
    const filtertedReponse = responses.filter(response => (response ? true : false));

    const indexes = yield call(getIndexedTagsIds);

    yield put(setTagImageSuccess({ image: filtertedReponse, indexes }));
  }
}
```

Comment: did you fork this task `getTagsAllImages `?

Answer (score 0):

Since `yield` will wait for response of all api calls, further api calls won't happen till api calls in `requests` are resolved. So, you need to use `flatMap` instead of `for` loop. This way all calls will happen without being blocked.

```
function* getTagsAllImages(dataList = []) {
  const chunkedList = yield call(chunk, dataList, 5);

    const requests = chunkedList.flatMap(list => 
 list.map(item => call(getStoreLableimage, item._id, item.image)));

    const responses = yield all(requests);
    const filtertedReponse = responses.filter(response => (response ? true : false));

    const indexes = yield call(getIndexedTagsIds);

    yield put(setTagImageSuccess({ image: filtertedReponse, indexes }));
}
```

References: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap

Comment: @asfath-shifan Did my solution solved your problem?

Comment: it doesn't send the api calls by chunk. using flatmap is just convert the chunk list to again as sequential array. which not work as i expect :(